# Llamar el Decorador de una SUPERCLASE a una SUBCLASE - Python

Tags: python, clase, decoradores, instancias

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Si tengo un DECORADOR en una SUPERCLASE
¿Como hago para usar este DECORADOR dentro de una instancia(SUBCLASE) de esta SUPERCLASE?

Segun mi codigo de Python, lo que quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
    @deco_silla_demontar
    def montabilidad(self):     #Pero SOLO para la SUBCLASE CABALLO
        ...

######## copiar de aqui para abajo #####

    class Moviles():

    def __init__(self, base_inferior, cant_base_inferior, base_superior, cant_base_superior, base_interna, tipo_base_interna, montable):
        self.baseinf = base_inferior
        self.cantbaseinf = cant_base_inferior
        self.basesup = base_superior
        self.cantbasesup = cant_base_superior
        self.baseint = base_interna
        self.tipobaseint = tipo_base_interna
        self.montado = montable      

    
    def deco_silla_demontar(*funcmod): 

        def funint(*args):           
            print("SE PUEDE MONTAR SOLO SI TIENE SILLA DE MONTAR")
            funcmod(*args)
        return funint

      
    def aceleracion(self, vf, vi, tf, ti):
        a = (vf - vi)/(tf-ti)
        print(f'La aceleracion de ... es {a}')


    def montabilidad(self):
        
        if self.montado == True:
            print("se puede montar")

        else:
            print("No se puede montar")
    
class Humano(Moviles):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Piernas", 2, "Manos", 2, "Corazon", "Organico", False)

class Caballo(Moviles):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Patas", 4, None, None, "Corazon", "Organico", True)

class Auto(Moviles):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Ruenas", 4, "Puertas", 4, "Motor", "Mecanico", True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Humano1 = Humano()
    print("Humano")
    Humano1.aceleracion(8,0,10,0)
    Humano1.montabilidad()

    print("""
    -----------
    """)


    Caballo1 = Caballo()
    print("Caballo")
    Caballo1.aceleracion(30,0,10,0)   
    Caballo1.montabilidad()    #Es este el que quiero decorar con @deco_silla_demontar
                               #He probado de todo y no encuentro la manera
                               #Ya que por logica, Humano y Auto no pueden tener Silla
                               #de montar
                           
    print("""
    -----------
    """)


    Auto1 = Auto()
    print("Auto")
    Auto1.aceleracion(160,0,10,0)
    Auto1.montabilidad()
```

Cuando decoro en la CLASS Moviles el metodo MONTAVILIDAD con @DECO_SILLA_DEMONTAR se aplica a HUMANOS, CABALLOS y AUTOS.

Lo que quiero es que solo se decore CABALLOS.

Probé por herencia, introducir el codigo dentro de la CLASS CABALLOS y todo bien, pero la idea es reutilizar el codigo de CLASS MOVILES ¿Es posible?

Entre varias cosas que he probado, me sale "bound method" que no se que es (recien estoy aprendiendo Python), llevo todo el día con esto.

Se agradece!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que hay varios errores de conceptos y da la impresión de que quieres usar un decorador a la fuerza. Solo porque sí.

Sin embargo, en efecto es posible lo que quieres hacer. Tanto de manera estática (usando la sintaxis de decoración de Python (`@`)), como de manera dinámica, o en Runtime.

```py
class Moviles:

    # Todo lo demás que tienes en tu clase

    @staticmethod
    def deco_silla_demontar(funcmod):
        def funint(*args):
            print("SE PUEDE MONTAR SOLO SI TIENE SILLA DE MONTAR")
            return funcmod(*args)
        return funint
    
    # Todo lo demás que tienes en tu clase
```

De manera estática:

```
class Caballo(Moviles):
    @Moviles.deco_silla_demontar
    def montabilidad(self):
        super().montabilidad()
```

O en runtime:

```
class Caballo(Moviles):
    # Todo lo demás que tienes en tu clase


caballo = Caballo()
caballo.montabilidad = Moviles.deco_silla_demontar(caballo.montabilidad)
```

De cualquier manera, cuando invoques `caballo.montabilidad()`, obtendrás:

```
>>> caballo.montabilidad()
SE PUEDE MONTAR SOLO SI TIENE SILLA DE MONTAR
se puede montar
```

Nota que `deco_silla_demontar()` (el decorador) está siendo definido como un método estático para evitar que Python pase el argumento `self` a la función cuando esta sea invocada, ya que, de cualquier manera, no se estaría haciendo nada con él.

Esto te da una pista de que el decorador realmente no pertenece a la clase `Moviles`. No tiene sentido declararlo allí. Pero, como dije, y solo para responder a tu pregunta original: Sí es posible hacerlo y sería de esa manera.

---

P.D: Las funciones a las cuales Python pasa el argumento `self` automáticamente son las que se conocen, precisamente, como *bound methods*. Son aquellas que han sido asociadas a un objeto en particular.

Python hace esa asociación, por defecto, para todas las funciones que se declaran en la clase de un objeto.

Comment: Hola! 
Muchas gracias!
Justo lo que estaba buscando, si lo estoy forzando ya que estoy aprendiendo y tenía la duda si se podía hacer eso o no.

Comment: Qué es lo que hace @staticmethod?

Comment: Hola, de nada. @staticmethod declara un metodo como estático y tiene el efecto que expliqué arriba.